# How to convert a virtual function with const noexcept from c++11 to c++17?

Tags: c++, clang, c++17

I'm sure this is an easy question for the c++17 gurus here.  I am trying to modernize some c++11 to gnu++17 using clang-tidy with clang-9 and getting confused about what clang-tidy is indicating to fix and how to fix it.

Here is some of the original code in the header file

```
namespace foo{
class bar {
 public:
  virtual ~bar() = default;
  virtual RealtimeConfig realtimeConfig() const noexcept = 0;
};
}
```

clang-tidy changes

> 'realtimeConfig' should be marked [[nodiscard]]

warning: use a trailing return type for this function

> virtual RealtimeConfig realtimeConfig() const noexcept = 0;
>
> ```
>       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
>       auto                                           -> RealtimeConfig
> ```

I've read the documentation here [CPP](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) but I do not understand what is the purpose of the following

> const noexcept = 0;

there seems to be nothing to throw so how does it return something? and so what do I need to do to pass clang-tidy?

If this is the wrong place for this question, let me know so I can move it.

Comment: is this really all the code that makes clang-tidy issue the warning? I dont know clang-tidy, but it looks a bit odd that it warns to add a trailing return type when you do not have `auto` on the method declaration. Also your question about `noexcept = 0;` seems to be unrelated to the warning from clang. Is it not your code? Who put the `noexcept = 0;` there? Btw the `const` does not belong to the `noexcept` but it declares the method as a `const` method

Comment: in other words: Please provide a [mcve] and please one question per question

Comment: `clang-tidy`, like quite a few such tools, often issues "recommendations" based on subjective concerns (e.g.  style, preferences advocated by particular people or groups including the authors, etc).    This means you should treat the messages as "options to consider" rather than "directions to follow to make your code better".   You might have perfectly good reasons not to specify `[[nodiscard]]` or not to use training return types -  in which case blindly addressing the warnings from `clang-tidy` is counter-productive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first warning tells you to use the [`nodiscard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) attribute:

```
[[nodiscard]] virtual RealtimeConfig realtimeConfig() const noexcept = 0;
```

this will issue a compiler warning if someone calls `realtimeConfig` without using the returned value.

The second warning is a a personal style thing. It just tells you to use trailing return types:

```
virtual auto realtimeConfig() const noexcept -> RealtimeConfig = 0;
```

This has no benefit or disadvantages tho.

The `const noexcept = 0;` are actually three different things:

1. `const` restricts the member function to use `const this` instead of `this`. This basically means you cannot modify members of your class and only call other `const` member functions.
2. `noexcept` is a guarantee that your function will not throw any exceptions. If it does, the program is terminated.
3. `= 0` can only be used in conjunction with `virtual`. It declares a pure virtual function (other languages call them abstract functions).

All in all (according to your clang-tidy) your declaration should look like this:

```
[[nodiscard]] virtual auto realtimeConfig() const noexcept -> RealtimeConfig = 0;
```

That being said, it isn't much of a "modernization". The `[[nodiscard]]` is probably useful but some compilers just ignore it since they're not required to do anything. A `nodiscard` keyword would make much more sense imo but that's not considered for the standard atm.

Answer (score 1):

To convert your valid C++11 code to valid C++17 code all you need to do is **nothing**. What you're seeing there is **style advice**. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.